# auth could not identify password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, ping

My logs are completely taken up by these messages:

```
Apr 03 11:44:53 sudo:  pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [foo]
Apr 03 11:44:54 sudo:  pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
```

and I cannot ping my server anymore. Apart from that everything is working perfectly including ssh, SMTP and IMAP.

What is going on?

Comment: A `ping` is a very unreliable thing anyway, typically it is blocked by firewalls these days. Apart from that you need to find out what service causes these `pam` activities. That _might_ be the apache http server. Have you configured any http based authentication schemes in it? Take a look at its log files.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha I am running NGINX? What is a more reliable way of monitoring whether a server is online? I currently have a cron pinging my server 3 times every 5 mins and it has been working for year. Since last night it has stopped working. (About the time I started using a VPN)...

Comment: `ping` uses `icpm` packages, not `tcp`, those are handled different inside networks. I can very well believe that the huge modifications VPM does to your network stack have such side effects. But that is not the issue here. Question is what service uses PAM on your system. You did the setup, you should know... If you don't, then check each service that can be reached from the outside: check its log files for failed authentication attempts. Typical candidates are, if they are operated: http, ssh, ftp, smtp, imap4, ...